# I'm attempting to float 5 buttons from left to right

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I'm trying to have these 5 images to  line up left to right however they are stacking top to bottom.

This is my HTML code

```
<div style="backgroundColorButtons">
<img src="images/white01.jpg" alt= "White Background" width="236" height="35" type='button' value='White Background' onClick="javascript:changeBGC('#ffffff');return false"
onmouseover="this.src='images/white02.jpg';" 
  onmouseout="this.src='images/white01.jpg'" 
  onmousedown="this.src='images/white04.jpg'"
  onmouseup="this.src='images/white01.jpg'" />
</div>  

 <div style="backgroundColorButtons">
<img src="images/black01.jpg" alt= "Black Background" width="236" height="35" type="button" value='Black Background' onClick="javascript:changeBGC('#000000');return false" 
onmouseover="this.src='images/black02.jpg';" 
  onmouseout="this.src='images/black01.jpg'" 
  onmousedown="this.src='images/black04.jpg'"
  onmouseup="this.src='images/black01.jpg'" />
  </div>

<div style="backgroundColorButtons">
<img src="images/red01.jpg" alt= "Red Background" width="236" height="35" type='button' value='Red Background' onClick="javascript:changeBGC('#ff0000');return false" 
onmouseover="this.src='images/red02.jpg';" 
  onmouseout="this.src='images/red01.jpg'" 
  onmousedown="this.src='images/red04.jpg'"
  onmouseup="this.src='images/red01.jpg'" />
  </div>
```

There are two more buttons with similar code
This is the CSS Code that I am using;

```
.backgroundColorButtons{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: I am curious as to how this works `style="backgroundColorButtons"`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `style` use `class`

```
<div class="backgroundColorButtons">
```

I've also noticed that the way you use JS to change states is pretty painful, both for you, somebody who will edit the code one day, and the user it self. On every event (till all images are cached by the browser) you request the server for a new image resulting in an unprofessional time gap / wait - for the new image to be loaded.

Avoid where possible (anywhere is possible) inline JavaScript.
Explore the *sprite images* technique.

Answer (score 1):

```
#container
{display:table;width:100%;}
#row{display:table-row;}
.left{display:table-cell;padding:10px;}
```

**the html**

```
   <div id="container">
   <div id="row">
        <div class="left">1st image</div>
            <div class="left">2nd  image</div>
            <div class="left">3rd  image</div>  
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  oh ya :D .... i just copy-pasted from my  work , where float:none; was necessary

Comment: Still I really don't know what's wrong with `float:left;` It's a perfectly fine property!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ofcourse yep ; but at certain situations this code helped (for at least me) ; so posted here ,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

In your div declaration you have invalid syntax:

```
<div style="backgroundColorButtons">
```

If you want to assign class `backgroundColorButtons` to a div, you need to change it to:

```
<div class="backgroundColorButtons">
```

`<div style="">` is allowed. but is used only for defining inline style, like so:

```
<div style="float: left;">
```

You should also consider defining `width` for your floated elements.

Comment: Why should `width` be considered for `float`ed elements?

Comment: Because if a floated element's width is not set to a suitable width (so that all the elements fit in one row, as desired), it may happen for that floated element to push the next floated element below.

Answer (score 1):

try using class instead of style should work

In Example `<div class="backgroundColorButtons">`

Answer (score 0):

```
try to use .class in place of style="backgroundColorButtons" and style="backgroundColorButtons" is not valid inline css. you can do one of the below

1. add style="float:left"  in place of style="backgroundColorButtons"

or

2. Make class name as 

<style>
.backgroundColorButtons{
float:left;
}
</style>

and remove style in div add class="backgroundColorButtons"
```